# Is $A_a = \{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n\}$ a subset of $A = \{(a_1, b_1), (a_2,b_2), \ldots, (a_n,b_n)\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A = \{(a_1, b_1), (a_2,b_2), \ldots, (a_n,b_n)\}$ be a set. $a,b$ may be numbers, generic objects.

Take the set $A_a = \{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n\}$

Does there exist any formal relationship between $A_a$ and $A$?

For instance, is $A_a$ a subset of $A$?

Is $A_a$ obtained by $A \backslash A_b$, where $A_b$ is analogously defined?

Comment: $A_a$ is most certainly not a subset (they have *NO* elements in common!).  $\phi: A\to A_a$ via $\phi;(a_n,b_n) \mapsto a_n$ is well-defined function.  $A$ is a s set of $2$-tuples (aka ordered pairs) and $\phi$ is called a "projection"; it maps a set of ordered pairs to their corresponding first term.

Comment: Actually I think the standard notation of $A= \{\textbf{x}_\alpha\}\subset X_1\times X_2 \times ...\times X_n$  is set of ordered $n$-tuples where each $\textbf{x}_\alpha = (x_{\alpha_1},x_{\alpha_2},....., x_{\alpha_n})$ is an orderded $n$-tuple.  Then $\pi_k: A \to X_k$ is the function for the projection that maps $\pi_k:  \textbf{x}=(x_{1},x_{2},....., x_{n})\mapsto x_{k}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely, not a subset since the elements of $A_a$ do not belong to $A$. You can think of $A$ as a subset of the Cartesian product of two sets $A_1$ and $A_2$, where the $a$'s and the $b$'s belong. Then $A_a$ would be the projection of $A$ onto the first factor of the product.

Comment: Good ole projection. Thanks!